# AWS Glue Crawlers add partitions within exclude pattern conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I ran into the following situation: let's say I have the following s3 structure

- s3://my_bucket/path_to_crawl/partition=A/some_file.parquet
- s3://my_bucket/path_to_crawl/partition=B/some_file.parquet
- s3://my_bucket/path_to_crawl/partition=C/some_file.csv

I point my crawler to s3://my_bucket/path_to_crawl and it has the following exclude pattern defined: `**.csv`. The desired output would be a table `path_to_crawl` created with 2 partitions `s3://my_bucket/path_to_crawl/partition=A/` and `s3://my_bucket/path_to_crawl/partition=B/`, however the crawler also adds partition `s3://my_bucket/path_to_crawl/partition=C/`. The crawler does not however create a separate table for the last partition which is desired as not having the exclude patter would create a separate table.

The problem here is that in table path_to_crawl partition `s3://my_bucket/path_to_crawl/partition=C/` inherits schema from the table and when trying to query it through e.g. Athena - the query naturally errors out as it encounters incompatible schema.

Is there a way to make exclude patterns not add the partition to the table as well?

Comment: Partitions are use to divide large data set into smaller chunks. But all these chunks must have same schema.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make exclude patterns not add the partition to the table as well?

You'll have to explicitly exclude the path of the partition.

Include path:

```
s3://my_bucket/path_to_crawl
```

Exclude paths:

```
**.csv
partition=C/*
```